# Input value not changing with user input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working my way through the Odin Project, attempting to make the "etch-a-sketch" type website with jQuery. The idea is to have a div with a grid inside of it that when moused over, the grid squares change color. The user should also be able to input how many grid squares they want, so if they put 16 in the form, they'll get a 16x16 grid.

I set an initial value to 16. When I input a different number and hit "go", the value just changes back to 16 and the grid remains the same. Where am I going wrong?

Thanks!

Relevant code is as follows:

HTML:

```
<form>
    <label>Enter the width in pixels:</label>
    <input id="formbox" type="text" value="16">
    <input id="setWidth" class="buttons" type="submit" value="Go!">
    <button id="reset" class="buttons" type="reset">Reset</button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$('#setWidth').click(function () {
    $('.box').css("background-color", "#fff");
    $('.box').remove();

    var $divWidth = $('#formbox').val();

    for (var i = 0; i < $divWidth; i++) {
        $('#canvas').append('<div class="divHolder"></div>');
        $('.divHolder').css("height", Math.floor(500 / $divWidth));
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < $divWidth; i++) {
        $('.divHolder').append('<div class="box"></div>');
        $('.box').css("width", Math.floor(500 / $divWidth));
        $('.box').css("height", Math.floor(500 / $divWidth));
    }
});
```

Comment: Well, you're submitting the form, reloading the page, what did you expect when using a `submit` button ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the `preventDefault()` function on the event.

This function stops the default behaviour (in this instance, a refresh of the page is the behaviour that should be expected by default).

```
$('#setWidth').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.box').css("background-color", "#fff");
    $('.box').remove();

    var $divWidth = $('#formbox').val();

    for (var i = 0; i < $divWidth; i++) {
        $('#canvas').append('<div class="divHolder"></div>');
        $('.divHolder').css("height", Math.floor(500 / $divWidth));
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < $divWidth; i++) {
        $('.divHolder').append('<div class="box"></div>');
        $('.box').css("width", Math.floor(500 / $divWidth));
        $('.box').css("height", Math.floor(500 / $divWidth));
    }
});
```

Comment: Along with this, the user would probably change `type="submit"` to `type="button"`.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Nope, not at all. Look at the snippet again (I've added an example). You can try this yourself, no changes to the type are needed.

Comment: @SysVoid I think your missing my message, I'm simply stating it's more appropriate since the button clearly isn't  for submitting.

Comment: Well, they are technically still submitting the data, even if a refresh is not happening. I guess that could be down to personal opinion right there.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I guess that's one way of looking at it, but it might be a good idea if we stick to what the OP wants just in case there's some weird reason (which I can't think of, lol).